# Gnuplot: sum occurrences in time interval

Tags: statistics, gnuplot

i'm having a csv like this

```
2021-10-31;20:30:26
2021-10-31;20:32:15
2021-10-31;20:39:17
2021-10-31;20:40:15
2021-10-31;20:42:13
2021-11-01;08:37:15
...
```

i would like to calculate the entries within a 10 minute interval and display it in an bar graph. In the example above there are from 20:30 till 20:40 there are 3 hits, from 20:40 till 20:50 there ar 2 hits, and so on.

Is there any way to ge this done with gnuplot? Or do i've to prepare the data?

Thank you, Martin

Comment: Problem solved? Question answered? Any feedback would be appreciated. This holds for your other questions as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `smooth frequency` option like this:

```
reset

# formatting of output data (graph)
set format x "%Y-%m-%d\n%H:%M" timedate

# y-axis, bar graph should start at 0
set yrange [0:*]
set ylabel "Occurences"
set ytics 1 

# make some space for large x axis labels
set rmargin at screen 0.95

# put input values into bins/time intervals
binwidth=10*60  # 10 minutes in seconds
bin(val) = binwidth * floor(val/binwidth)

# configure bar graph
set boxwidth binwidth

# final plot command
plot "a.dat" using (bin(timecolumn(1, "%Y-%m-%d;%H:%M:%S"))):(1) smooth freq with boxes fs solid 0.25 notitle
```

Documentation from `help smooth freq`:

```
 The `frequency` option makes the data monotonic in x; points with the same
 x-value are replaced by a single point having the summed y-values.
 To plot a histogram of the number of data values in equal size bins,
 set the y-value to 1.0 so that the sum is a count of occurances in that bin:
 Example:
      binwidth = <something>  # set width of x values in each bin
      bin(val) = binwidth * floor(val/binwidth)
      plot "datafile" using (bin(column(1))):(1.0) smooth frequency
```

You have time data, so `column` must be replaced by `timecolumn`, see
`help timecolumn` for details.

The command `set boxwidth` is used by the boxes plotting style, see `help plotting styles boxes` for details.

This is the result:
[image: result image]